# Multithreading: chromedriver does not open url in second window

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, chromedriver

Java code in thread function,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir="+config.chromeUserDir);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--profile-directory="+profile);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

and create object and start in thread with following code

```
Driver d1 = new Driver(profile);
d1.start();

Driver d2 = new Driver(profile1);
d1.start();
```

Two different profiles have been created, code works well with single thread but with multiple threads it does not open google website in two separate windows, it says:

`Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac) on port 25692 Only local connections are allowed. Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac) on port 25954 Only local connections are allowed. Oct 14, 2018 2:10:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS Oct 14, 2018 2:10:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS Created new window in existing browser session.`

It opens google in only one window. The window opened by an another thread remains idle. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 4):

```
Driver d1 = new Driver(profile);
d1.start();

Driver d2 = new Driver(profile1);
d1.start();
```

Here you create `Driver d2` but start `d1.start()` the second time then (you have started it two lines of code before)

Answer (score 2):

You have not started d2. The code should look like this:

```
Driver d1 = new Driver(profile);
d1.start();

Driver d2 = new Driver(profile1);
d2.start();
```